# Changing background color of header and adding logo after certain point

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a web page that needs its background color to change from transparent to black and adding a logo after after reaching a point scrolling.
I'm new to javascript and I have some problems with this.

Example : http://www.asi.media/

Currently I'm stuck at changing color but can't figure out how to also show the image.
I've tried multiple solutions that I found browsing but none of those worked.

Can you help me little?

HTML:

```
<body>
    <img src="pictures/placeholder1.jpg" id="first_image">
    <header>
        <img src="pictures/logo.png">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">PROIZVODI</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">O GALERIJI</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">O NAMA</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">TIM</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">KONTAKT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main>


    </main>
```

CSS:

```css
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: fixed;
    font-size: 14px;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: transparent;
}

header img {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 15%;
    height: 80%;
    margin-top: 5px;
    display: none;
}

#first_image {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 1024px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -2;
}
```

Javascript (jQuery):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function() { 
        if ($(document).scrollTop() > 600) {
            $("#header").css("background-color", "black");
        } else {
            $("#header").css("background-color", "transparent");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: it should be `$('header')`  not `$('#header')`

Comment: @Thielicious it still doesn't work...

Comment: check my answer @Antonio Gvardijan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 600) {
    $("header").css("background", "black");
    $("header img").css('visibility','visible');
  } else {
    $("header").css("background", "transparent");
    $("header img").css('visibility','hidden');
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Thielicious/jykvt19k/